# Jenkins install failes

Tags: ubuntu, jenkins

I'm trying to install jenkins on Ubuntu 16, but it always fails.

It shows:

```
Job for jenkins.service failed because the control process exited with error code. 
See "systemctl status jenkins.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.
invoke-rc.d: initscript jenkins, action "start" failed.
```

I've checked my JDK version,

```
openjdk version "1.8.0_275"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_275-8u275-b01-0ubuntu1~16.04-b01)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.275-b01, mixed mode)
```

And also add java path to `/etc/init.d/jenkins`

```
PATH=/bin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/usr/sbin:/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8.0-openjdk-amd64/bin/java
JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8.0-openjdk-amd64
CLASS_PATH=$JAVA_HOME/lib
PATH=$PATH:$JAVA_HOME/bin
export PATH JAVA_HOME CLASSPATH
```

I still failed in jenkins installation. Anyone knows how to fix this?

Comment: Could you post some of the logs? At least the result of the journalctl -xe command

Answer (score 0):

Fine. I figure it out.

`invoke-rc.d: initscript jenkins, action "start" failed.`

This error tells a wrong version of JDK.
The Ubuntu16 has two version of jdk, java8 and java9. I set the environment path to java8, so, when I check the JAVA version, it shows me a correct version. But jenkins searched java in `/usr/bin/java`, it is still a soft link to java9. That's why my jenkins always starts failed.

After Relink the `/usr/bin/java` to my java8 path, then restart jenkins, jenkins works.